# binding ObjectiveC to C# - btouch unexpected error

Tags: binding, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I try to bind the ArcGIS SDK for a Xamarin Project. I already have build a fat library and use Objective Sharpie to create the ApiDefination.cs and StructsAndEnums.cs. I fixed all issues, warnings and errors in the binding project but when i build the project i get the following build log:

```
Build started 05.08.2015 13:56:38.
Project "/Users/macbook/Bindings/Iseo.Esri.ObjCBinding/Iseo.Esri.ObjCBinding.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Target _CreateGeneratedSourcesDir:
Created directory "obj/Debug/ios/"
Target _CollectBundleResources:
CollectBundleResources Task
BundleResources:
OptimizePNGs: False
ProjectDir: /Users/macbook/Bindings/Iseo.Esri.ObjCBinding
ResourcePrefix: Resources
Target _CreateEmbeddedResources:
CreateEmbeddedResources Task
BundleResources:
Prefix: monotouch
Target PrepareForBuild:
Configuration: Debug Platform: AnyCPU
Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
No input files were specified for target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies, skipping.
Target _GenerateBindings:
BTouchEmitDebugInformation: false
BTouch Task
BTouchToolPath: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/
BTouchToolExe: btouch-native
AdditionalLibPaths:
AllowUnsafeBlocks: True
ApiDefinitions:
ApiDefinition.cs
BaseLibDll: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/    Xamarin.iOS.dll
CompilerPath:
CoreSources:
StructsAndEnums.cs
DefineConstants: MOBILE;IOS;DEBUG;
EmitDebugInformation: False
GeneratedSourcesDir: obj/Debug/ios/
GeneratedSourcesFileList: obj/Debug/ios//sources.list
Namespace:
NativeLibraries:
NoStdLib: False
OutputAssembly:
References:
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.dll
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.iOS.dll
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.Core.dll
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/mscorlib.dll
Resources:
Sources:
Tool /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/btouch-native execution started with arguments: /v /baselib:/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.iOS.dll /unsafe /d:"MOBILE;IOS;DEBUG" ApiDefinition.cs /s:StructsAndEnums.cs -r      /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.dll -r /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.iOS.dll -r /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.Core.dll -r /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/mscorlib.dll /tmpdir:obj/Debug/ios/ /sourceonly:obj/Debug/ios//sources.list
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/smcs -debug -unsafe -target:library -nowarn:436 -out:'obj/Debug/ios/temp.dll' -r:/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.10.3.2/lib/btouch/btouch-native.exe -r:'/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.dll' -r:'/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.iOS.dll' -r:'/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.Core.dll' -r:'/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/mscorlib.dll' -unsafe -r:'/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.iOS.dll' -define:MOBILE;IOS;DEBUG 'ApiDefinition.cs' 'StructsAndEnums.cs'

BTOUCH: error BI0000: Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at Generator.GetGetterExportAttribute (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pinfo) [0x0002c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1962/8b265d64/source/maccore/src/generator.cs:2247
at Generator.GenerateProtocolTypes (System.Type type, System.String class_visibility, System.String TypeName, System.String protocol_name, Foundation.ProtocolAttribute protocolAttribute) [0x00405] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1962/8b265d64/source/maccore/src/generator.cs:4943
at Generator.Generate (System.Type type) [0x002a5] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1962/8b265d64/source/maccore/src/generator.cs:5131
at Generator.Go () [0x00b97] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1962/8b265d64/source/maccore/src/generator.cs:2504
at BindingTouch.Main2 (System.String[] args) [0x00ccd] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1962/8b265d64/source/maccore/src/btouch.cs:405
at BindingTouch.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0001d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1962/8b265d64/source/maccore/src/btouch.cs:89
WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
Using default runtime: v4.0.30319
Task "BTouch" execution -- FAILED
Done building target "_GenerateBindings" in project "/Users/macbook/Bindings/Iseo.Esri.ObjCBinding/Iseo.Esri.ObjCBinding.csproj".-- FAILED

Done building project "/Users/macbook/Bindings/Iseo.Esri.ObjCBinding/Iseo.Esri.ObjCBinding.csproj".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.
Errors:

/Users/macbook/Bindings/Iseo.Esri.ObjCBinding/Iseo.Esri.ObjCBinding.csproj  (Build) ->
  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.ObjCBinding.CSharp.targets (_GenerateBindings target) ->

BTOUCH: error BI0000: Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at          http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.8843620

--------------------- Fertig ---------------------

Build: 1 Fehler, 0 Warnungen
```

I hope someone has any suggestions to push me to the solution.

Comment: Do as the error message says, and file a bug (with the binding project), and we'll look at it.

Comment: allready done here is the link: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=32796